# How to parse a very huge XML file from a remote server rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml

I have a very large XML from a remote server which I have to parse and get the data.

I have tried to open the file using the open() function but it is taking more than 15 minutes and still no response.

Then I tried Nokogiri::XML(open(URL)) where URL is the link which contains the data to parse.

Also, I have tried using Net::HTTP::Get but again with no fruitful results.

Can anyone suggest which gem and function can be used to parse the data?

Answer (score 1):

As [mentioned before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38099724/2866660), [`Nokogiri::XML::Reader`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/nokogiri/1.5.0/Nokogiri/XML/Reader) is your friend here. The example in the documentation works fine if you have the file locally.

It is also possible to parse the data as soon as it comes in, fully streaming. This involves getting the data in chunks (e.g. using [`Net::HTTP`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html)) and connecting it to the `Nokogiri::XML::Reader` by means of an [`IO.pipe`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/IO.html#method-c-pipe).

Example (adapted from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/wvengen/3a93e1f55d5d412b1d1b197150550edd)):

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'net/http'

# setup request
uri = URI("http://example.com/articles.xml")
req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)

# read response in a separate thread using a pipe to communicate
rd, wr = IO.pipe
reader_thread = Thread.new do
  Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port, use_ssl: uri.scheme == 'https') do |http|
    http.request(req) do |response|
      response.read_body {|chunk| wr.write(chunk) }
    end
    wr.close
  end
end

# parse the incoming data chunk by chunk
reader = Nokogiri::XML::Reader(rd)
reader.each do |node|
  next if node.node_type != Nokogiri::XML::Reader::TYPE_ELEMENT
  next if node.name != "article"

  # now that we have the desired fragment, put it to use
  doc = Nokogiri::XML(node.outer_xml)
  puts("Got #{doc.text}")
end
rd.close

# let the reader thread finish cleanly
reader_thread.join
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with large XML files then you can use Nokogiri::XML::Reader class. I have successfully opened 1 GB files without any problems. For optimal performance you could download the file first and then parse it using XML::Reader class localy on your server

The usage is something like this (replace XML_FILE with your path):

```
Nokogiri::XML::Reader(File.open(XML_FILE)).each do |node|
  if node.name == 'Node' && node.node_type == Nokogiri::XML::Reader::TYPE_ELEMENT
    puts node.outer_xml # you can do something like this also Nokogiri::XML(node.outer_xml).at('./Node')
  end
end
```

Heere is the documentation: http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/master/Nokogiri/XML/Reader

Hope it helps

Comment: The size of the file is almost 2 GB. Will Nokogiri::XML::Reader class be helpful?

Comment: Should not be a problem. But I would say download the file first using NET object or similar and then parsing locally. Reader class is designed to open very big files.

Comment: Okay will try that